# Windows Password reset over web

Tags: iis, password

I have a maybe silly question. If you host a Website on an ISS web server and give your employees a link where they can authenticate with the windows passwords they use in the office.

Let's say john doe with the  windows password 12345 authenticates on https://mywebsite.com/ to see his time schedule for work next week

Is it possible to let the user reset his password from home with a password reset link sent by mail in the same way he sit in front of a windows 10 workstation in the office and reset an expired password.?

Or in other wods is ist possible to extend an authenticate dialog with a password reset link and how.

Comment: yes and no. There's nothing that I'm aware of that is built in and easy. But there are probably 3rd party products and/or you can write your own code to do so. I did it for my organization using basic HTML and PHP to call a powershell script on the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to understand that there is a difference between a `Password reset` and a `Password change` in Windows.

An administrator can reset a user's password and may destroy potentially crucial user data in the process.

A user password can be changed by providing the old password and a new one.

Windows does not come with any builtin features to change a Windows password through a web page. (except for PowerShell Web Access which would be overkill).

So you could build your own web pages that allows a user to change their password. You would need to call a Win32 API function to do this through a web page. I don't think there is a managed (dot.net) method for this.

There is also a question about local accounts vs. domain accounts.

For security reasons I would stay away of implementing such a feature.

If you want to reset a password, you would need to run the web site under a privileged account or implement some sort of background process that picks up reset requests from the web page. All not trivial and not recommended unless you really know what you are doing.